# OWL API, extracting a string from a URI

Tags: java, owl-api

Given an arbitrary IRI, such as the main ontology or one of the ontologies it imports, I would like to extract the title but the code yields no annotations.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about, from the SKOS ontology:

```
  <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core">
    <dct:title xml:lang="en">SKOS Vocabulary</dct:title>
```

How exactly would I extract, "SKOS Vocabulary".

Here is some code I am currently using from an OWL-API tutorial.

```
public void testingOWL() throws OWLOntologyCreationException, OWLOntologyStorageException
{

// Get hold of an ontology manager 
OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager(); 

// Load an ontology from the Web.  We load the ontology from a document IRI 
IRI docIRI = IRI.create("http://www.w3.org/2009/08/skos-reference/skos.rdf"); 
OWLOntology skos = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(docIRI); 

System.out.println("Loaded ontology: " + skos); 
System.out.println();

// Save a local copy of the ontology.  (Specify a path appropriate to your setup) 
File file = new File("e:/downloadAndSaveOWLFile.owl"); 
manager.saveOntology(skos, IRI.create(file.toURI())); 

// Ontologies are saved in the format from which they were loaded.   
// We can get information about the format of an ontology from its manager 
OWLOntologyFormat format = manager.getOntologyFormat(skos); 
System.out.println("    format: " + format); 
System.out.println();

// Save the ontology in owl/xml format 
OWLXMLOntologyFormat owlxmlFormat = new OWLXMLOntologyFormat(); 

// Some ontology formats support prefix names and prefix IRIs.   
// In our case we loaded the pizza ontology from an rdf/xml format, which supports prefixes.  
// When we save the ontology in the new format we will copy the prefixes over  
// so that we have nicely abbreviated IRIs in the new ontology document 
if(format.isPrefixOWLOntologyFormat()) 
{ 
    owlxmlFormat.copyPrefixesFrom(format.asPrefixOWLOntologyFormat()); 
} 

manager.saveOntology(skos, owlxmlFormat, IRI.create(file.toURI())); 

// Dump an ontology to System.out by specifying a different OWLOntologyOutputTarget 
// Note that we can write an ontology to a stream in a similar way  
// using the StreamOutputTarget class 
OWLOntologyDocumentTarget documentTarget = new SystemOutDocumentTarget(); 

// Try another format - The Manchester OWL Syntax 
ManchesterOWLSyntaxOntologyFormat manSyntaxFormat = new ManchesterOWLSyntaxOntologyFormat(); 

if(format.isPrefixOWLOntologyFormat()) 
{ 
    manSyntaxFormat.copyPrefixesFrom(format.asPrefixOWLOntologyFormat()); 
} 
manager.saveOntology(skos, manSyntaxFormat, documentTarget); 
}
```

EDIT: Update the code based on the suggestion below but only returns 1 object for rdfs:seeAlso.

public void getData() throws OWLOntologyCreationException

```
{
    // Get hold of an ontology manager 
    OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();

    // Load an ontology from the Web.  We load the ontology from a document IRI 
    IRI docIRI = IRI.create("http://www.w3.org/2009/08/skos-reference/skos.rdf"); 
    OWLOntology skos = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(docIRI); 

    for (OWLAnnotation ann: skos.getAnnotations())
    {
        System.out.println("ann: " + ann.getProperty());
        System.out.println();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The annotation you're looking for is an ontology annotation, meaning the IRI that is its subject is the ontology IRI itself. This is accessed differently from standard annotations.

```
OWLOntology o= ... // init the ontology as usual
for (OWLAnnotation ann: o.getAnnotations()){
    if(ann.getProperty().equals(dataFactory.getRDFSLabel()){
        // here you have found a rdfs:label annotation, so you can use the value for your purposes
    }
}
```

Edit: Example of use

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws OWLOntologyCreationException {
    OWLOntologyManager m = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
    OWLOntology o = m.loadOntology(IRI
            .create("http://www.w3.org/2009/08/skos-reference/skos.rdf"));
    for (OWLAnnotation a : o.getAnnotations()) {
        System.out.println("TestSkos.main() " + a);
    }
}
Output:

    TestSkos.main() Annotation(rdfs:seeAlso <http://www.w3.org/TR/skos-reference/>)
    TestSkos.main() Annotation(<http://purl.org/dc/terms/creator> "Alistair Miles")
    TestSkos.main() Annotation(<http://purl.org/dc/terms/description> "An RDF vocabulary for describing the basic structure and content of concept schemes such as thesauri, classification schemes, subject heading lists, taxonomies, 'folksonomies', other types of controlled vocabulary, and also concept schemes embedded in glossaries and terminologies."@en)
    TestSkos.main() Annotation(<http://purl.org/dc/terms/contributor> "Participants in W3C's Semantic Web Deployment Working Group.")
    TestSkos.main() Annotation(<http://purl.org/dc/terms/creator> "Sean Bechhofer")
    TestSkos.main() Annotation(<http://purl.org/dc/terms/contributor> "Nikki Rogers")
    TestSkos.main() Annotation(<http://purl.org/dc/terms/title> "SKOS Vocabulary"@en)
    TestSkos.main() Annotation(<http://purl.org/dc/terms/contributor> "Dave Beckett")
```

Comment: Unfortunately the code above yields only one annotation which is for rdfs:seeAlso. It is not finding <dct:title xml:lang="en">SKOS Vocabulary</dct:title>.

Comment: Which OWL API version are you using? I get them all. See updated snippet.

Comment: I was using version 3.** but I switched to 4.** and it works perfect. Thanks!

Comment: How do you get the title for one of the imported ontologies?

Comment: @Ignazio: I'd like to know this as well.

Comment: @jpravato you can iterate over the set of imported ontologies with OWLOntology.getImportsClosure(). This collection includes the main ontology itself. For each of the contained ontologies, you can apply the same code - there's no difference for the imported ontologies, they all implement the same interface.